# Scroll passed by ListBox and handled by ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, windows-8

In Windows 8 app I have construction like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <Grid>
       <TextBlock/>
       <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
       <TextBlock/>
       <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
       <TextBlock/>
       <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And I need to handle scrolling by ScrollViewer (now each ListBox handle it). It's possible without adding `IsEnabled="false"`?

Comment: did you try handling `UIElement.PreviewMouseWheel` event on `ListBox`?

Comment: no, explain, please, how correct handle and redirect to ScrollViewer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this resource into your `ScrollViewer` and this should solve your issue:

```
<ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ScrollViewer.Resources>
```

this way you eliminate `ScrollViewer` which is normally part of `ListBox` template

Comment: Thanks it's helps,. Just remove TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" to TargetType="ListBox"